# Rendering issue with Firefox 57 (Quantum)

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, firefox-quantum

We have gotten some reports and also experienced this ourselves that on random occasions (maybe every third or fourth request) on our "apps pages" the page just becomes extremely long and the "footer" isn't loaded.

So for example on https://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-photoshop/ if you refresh that page a couple of time or go to any other "apps-page" this should happen.

[image]

The strange thing is that as soon as i open the inspector everything goes back to normal. Also if i have the inspector open everything works fine (but you can see the scrollbar jumping quickly as the problem appears but goes back again).

I have experienced this both with a Firefox with add-ons but also on a clean profile.

I suppose this is some bug with Firefox in combination with something in our code in the page.

Can anybody maybe point me in the right direction here? I have tried

Comment: I was able to reproduce the bug by hovering over any element that responds to hovering over it. Opening the inspector mysteriously fixes the bug until the page is reloaded. You should take a look at your mouseover events.